# Make a copy of an object inside another object. JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, object, copy

I have a problem.

I have a simple object like this:

```
var simpleObject = {

   name = "John",
   favColor = "blue
}
```

and another object with more properties and objects inside:

I want to put a COPY of simpleObject inside the bigger object like this:

```
biggerObject.copyofSimpleObject = simpleObject;
```

but what happens is whenever i change the value of simpleObject the value of biggerObject.copyofSimpleObject also changes.

So it seems like it's a reference to the original object which is a cool thing to do but in this situation I need it to be a copy so that when the original simpleObject changes the biggerObject.copyofSimpleObject value stays the same. I know it's probably simple but I don't know how to do this because I'm a noob. Please help :) Thank you! This is all javascript I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do:

```
var bigObject = {copyObject:simpleObject}
```

And define your simpleObject like this:

```
var simpleObject = {
   name : "John",
   favColor :"blue"
}
```

And then you can access it using:

```
bigObject.simpleObject
```